# Access to classes and functions from outside the application

Tags: c++

consider we have a program which manages collision detection between 100 rects(Rectangles).
and we have a class or function for collision detection between two rects (CCollisionCheck or CollidsTo ... for example).
and consider for some rects , we have some conditions which affect the collision detection.
for example we wanna exclude RED rects. or check BLUE rects only against GREEN ones.
any arbitrary condition.

I wanna write the necessary code ,for managing the condition , using my exe classes (CCollisionCheck ) or functions (CollidsTo ...), outside the exe.

can any one help me please?
How can I access my classes and function from outside the application?

Comment: You can't change the behaviour of your application once it's been compiled to an executable.

Comment: This is only possible if the program has an interface for dynamically loading new code (e.g.:via a `dll`, or by providing support for scripting).

Comment: @OliCharlesworth of course you can. Depends on the interface the exe or dll provides.

Comment: @LuchianGrigore: Indeed.  But I was interpreting the OP's question as meaning he already has some arbitrary exe, whose behaviour he now wants to modify externally.  But I may have that wrong!

Answer (score 0):

Since you said `exe`, I'll assume you're on Windows.

You can export and import classes and methods to and from an exe just like you would do with a dll.

You need a macro `DLLIMPEXP` which expands to

```
declspec(dllexport)
```

when compiling the exe and

```
declspec(dllimport)
```

when you include the headers in a different project. Look these up. Using them, you can specify which symbols to export.

Link the other project to the `lib` generated when compiling the exe and include the headers where your functions and classes are declared.

Comment: thank you. but I still need to use function pointers. I think I need to access DLLs from application. I may declare some abstract class and derive my classes in DLL from it.